# OpenMP paralleling GSL Ordinary Differential Equations calculation

Tags: c, openmp, gsl

I'm trying to parallelize my code, but i got errors. I need to calc a Cauchy problem (it's already done) but than i need to parallelize it using OpenMP lib.

I've tried to write some code with OpenMP, but it's not working.

I've created a struct to collect result.

```
struct Dots {
    double par;
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

This is my target function with parameter.

```
int ode_func (double x, const double y[], double f[], void *params)
{

    double mu = *(int *)params;
    f[0] = x + 2 * y[0] / (1 + mu * mu);
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the main function. I currently didn't find a way how to create a array of arrays of struct, but this is not the main problem.

```
void calc_cauchy_problem(struct Dots ArrayOfDots[], double x_start, double x_end, double y_start,
        int count) {

    int dim = 1;
    double x = x_start;
    double y[1] = {y_start};
    int mu = 5;
    int param = 0;
    gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {ode_func, NULL, dim, &param};
    gsl_odeiv2_driver * d = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys,
                                                               gsl_odeiv2_step_rkf45, 1e-6, 1e-6, 0.0);
    int status = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for shared(ArrayOfDots) private(sys, param, d, status)
    for (int param = 1; param < mu; param++) {

        gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {ode_func, NULL, dim, &param};
        gsl_odeiv2_driver * d = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys,
                                                               gsl_odeiv2_step_rkf45, 1e-6, 1e-6, 0.0);
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            double xi = x_start + i * (x_end - x_start) / count;

            int status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply(d, &x, xi, y);

            if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
            {
                printf ("error, return value=%d\n", status);
                break;
            }
           // ArrayOfDots[i].par = mu;
           // ArrayOfDots[i].x = xi;
           // ArrayOfDots[i].y = y[0];
        }
        gsl_odeiv2_driver_free (d);
    }

}
```

The main

```
int main() {
    double x_start = 0;
    double x_end = 10;
    double y_start = 0;
    int count = 10;
    struct Dots ArrayOfDots[count];
    calc_cauchy_problem(ArrayOfDots, x_start, x_end, y_start, count);
    return 0;
}
```

It's compiled successfully with this `gcc main.c -o main -fopenmp -lgsl -std=gnu11` but when i launch it i got error

```
gsl: driver.c:354: ERROR: integration limits and/or step direction not consistent
Default GSL error handler invoked.
```

I think that the main problem with this `#pragma omp parallel for shared(ArrayOfDots) private(sys, param, d, status)` but i have no idea how to rewrite this in the other way.
Thanks for your responses.

UPD:

With Kaveh Vahedipour help my code partially start to work. It means that half of my for cycle start to work. 
UPD UPD:
After another investigations i had the following code:
It's compile and run, but i got `Process finished with exit code 4` and `printf("Elapsed time = %f\n", omp_get_wtime() - start_time);` don't print anything.

```
struct Dots {
    double par;
    double x;
    double y;
};

int ode_func (double x, const double y[], double f[], void *params)
{

    double mu = *(int *)params;
    f[0] = (x + 2 * y[0]) / (1 + mu * mu);
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}
void calc_cauchy_problem(double x_start, double x_end, double y_start,
                         int count, int param1, int param2) {
    int dim = 1;
    double x = x_start;
    double y[1] = {y_start};
    int param = param1;
    int j = 0;
    int status = 0;
    char filename[10];

#pragma omp parallel for private(param, status, x, y)
    for (param = param1; param <= param2; param++) {
        struct Dots ArrayOfDots[count];
        gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {ode_func, NULL, dim, &param};
        gsl_odeiv2_driver * d =
                gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys, gsl_odeiv2_step_rkf45, 1e-6, 1e-6, 0.0);
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            double xi = x_start + i * (x_end - x_start) / count;

            int status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply(d, &x, xi, y);
            if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
            {
                printf ("error, return value=%d\n", status);
                break;
            }

            ArrayOfDots[i].par = param;
            ArrayOfDots[i].x = xi;
            ArrayOfDots[i].y = y[0];
        }
        gsl_odeiv2_driver_free (d);

    }
}
int main() {
    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    double x_start = 0;
    double x_end = 10;
    double y_start = 0;
    const int count = 500;
    int param1 = 1;
    int param2 = 10;
    calc_cauchy_problem(x_start, x_end, y_start, count, param1, param2);
    printf("Elapsed time = %f\n", omp_get_wtime() - start_time);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you could also post the main :)

Comment: Yea, i've updated.

Comment: cannot compile anymore. main does not fit new cauchy problem. please update all the code so it compiles again.

Comment: Did it. Check it.

Comment: look below for what i meant by put ArrayOfDots into loop

Comment: I can't understand which loop do you mean. :(

Comment: updated my code below.

Comment: I still see this errors. To reproduce this just need to increase range beetween param1 and param2, for example `int param1 = 1;`
  `int param2 = 6;`

Comment: no error on my side. the function below runs fine, when i remove the printf. you should not do output in the omp for loop. you should collect all data and print outside.

Comment: I tried to remove printf and erros disappear, yes, but for some reason i got next `Process finished with exit code 4` and programs runs very fast.

Comment: So, it still didn't work :(

Comment: Please always create a [mcve] (read the page carefully!) and double-check that... This saves everyone the trouble of going back and forth with incomplete versions of the code.

Comment: Okay, i've update my code with reproducible case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `x` to private loop vars: `private(sys, param, d, status, x)`. Please get back to me, if you still experience issues.

```
void calc_cauchy_problem(double x_start, double x_end, double y_start,
                         int count, int param1, int param2) {

  int dim = 1;
  double x = x_start;
  double y[1] = {y_start};
  int param = param1;
  int j = 0;
  int status = 0;
  char filename[10];

#pragma omp parallel for private(param, status, x, y)
  for (param = param1; param <= param2; param++) {
    struct Dots ArrayOfDots[count];
    gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {ode_func, NULL, dim, &param};
    gsl_odeiv2_driver * d =
      gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys, gsl_odeiv2_step_rkf45, 1e-6, 1e-6, 0.0);
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
      double xi = x_start + i * (x_end - x_start) / count;

      int status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply(d, &x, xi, y);
      if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
        {
          printf ("error, return value=%d\n", status);
          break;
        }
      ArrayOfDots[i].par = param;
      ArrayOfDots[i].x = xi;
      ArrayOfDots[i].y = y[0];
    }
    //write_data_to_file(param, count, ArrayOfDots);                                                                                        
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      printf ("%d: %f, %f, %f\n", omp_get_thread_num(),
              ArrayOfDots[i].par, ArrayOfDots[i].x, ArrayOfDots[i].y);
    }
    gsl_odeiv2_driver_free (d);
  }
}
```

Comment: Kaveh, seems like this didn't help me.I got this error again.

gsl: driver.c:354: ERROR: integration limits and/or step direction not consistent
Default GSL error handler invoked.
I got this by increasing parameter mu.

Comment: Will investigate later. With my kids on a hike now

Comment: Oh, Kaveh, i am so inattentive. This new problem caused by me - i didn't write "for" in pragma omp parallel. Now it works partially.

Comment: Great. Still would appreciate it, if you accepted the answer. :)

Comment: Can i accept it, if it partially help me? :)
Now i have a problem that i have only half of data. Another half just dropped with previous error.

Comment: Ok. Let's find the solution. When back will try to figure it out. Could you update your code to what you have right now?

Comment: Put ArrayOfDots into loop and remove from outside

Comment: It's already in loop. I just paste the bad version one. I'll edit it now.

Comment: So where should I look at the second version at the bottom? And does the code work correctly, when using OMP_NUM_THREADS=1

Comment: Really, I am happy to help, but you have not even made sure that the single threaded version works. When I comment out all the omp lines and run the code, I get `ERROR: integration limits and/or step direction not consistent`. And then you withdraw the points etc.

Comment: Seems like version with single thread doesn't work too. I'll try to fix it, and then will test version with multi-threads. Thanks for your answers, Kaveh.

Comment: Now i think that program runs correctly. Both versions works fine, and i can see the elapsed time difference between single-thread and multi-thread.

Comment: I would then appreciate, if you would accept the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this version works fine. I think problem was with this struct `Dots ArrayOfDots[count];` and when i try to push values to this struct.

```
      ArrayOfDots[i].par = param;
      ArrayOfDots[i].x = xi;
      ArrayOfDots[i].y = y[0];
```

Here is the full code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
// GSL lib includes
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>


int ode_func (double x, const double y[], double f[], void *params)
{

    double mu = *(int *)params;
    f[0] = (x + 2 * y[0]) / (1 + mu * mu);
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

void calc_cauchy_problem(double x_start, double x_end, double y_start,
                         int count, int param1, int param2) {

#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int param = param1; param < param2; param++) {
        gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {ode_func, NULL, 1, &param};

        gsl_odeiv2_driver * d =
                gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys, gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd,
                                               1e-6, 1e-6, 0.0);
        int i;
        double x = x_start, x1 = x_end;
        double y[1] = { y_start };

        for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            double xi = i * x1 / count;
            int status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply (d, &x, xi, y);

            if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
            {
                printf ("error, return value=%d\n", status);
                break;
            }

//            printf ("%d %d %.5e %.5e\n", omp_get_thread_num(), param, x, y[0]);
        }

        gsl_odeiv2_driver_free (d);
        }
    }

int main() {
    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    double x_start = 0;
    double x_end = 10;
    double y_start = 0;
    const int count = 100000;
    int param1 = 1;
    int param2 = 20;
    calc_cauchy_problem(x_start, x_end, y_start, count, param1, param2);
    printf("Elapsed time = %f\n", omp_get_wtime() - start_time);
    return 0;
}
```

Really thanks to Kaveh Vahedipour.